# Sed regex recognizing individual letters instead of words

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I created a file that logs the training of a random forest classifier and logistic regression. It has the following text:

```
Creating logistic regression model...
Done.
Creating random forest classifier model...
building tree 1 of 27
building tree 2 of 27
building tree 3 of 27
building tree 4 of 27
building tree 5 of 27
building tree 6 of 27
building tree 7 of 27
building tree 8 of 27
building tree 9 of 27
building tree 10 of 27
building tree 11 of 27
building tree 12 of 27
building tree 13 of 27
building tree 14 of 27
building tree 15 of 27
building tree 16 of 27
building tree 17 of 27
building tree 18 of 27
building tree 19 of 27
building tree 20 of 27
building tree 21 of 27
building tree 22 of 27
building tree 23 of 27
building tree 24 of 27
building tree 25 of 27
building tree 26 of 27
building tree 27 of 27
Train scores:
    Logistic Regression Recall: 0.6892336879192357
    Random Forest Recall: 0.5848905752422251
Test scores:
    Logistic Regression Recall: 0.6746186562629912
    Random Forest Recall: 0.5647724728982124
```

I'd like to extract just the score lines. I've tried `sed -n '/[Train|Test|Recall]/p' scores` (`scores` being the file name), but for some reason, even though `-n` is supposed to suppress all printing but the pattern-matched lines, it still prints the full text of the file.

When I ran `cat scores | grep "[Train|Test|Recall]" -`, the pattern-matching highlighter checked off the *letters* from each of those lines that seemed to match `[Train|Test|Recall]`, rather than the actual words: For example, `Creating logistic regression model...` had `_creatin_ l__istic re_ressi_n ___el...` highlighted. The problem persists even if I add boundaries: `cat scores | grep "[\bTrain\b|\bTest\b|\bRecall\b]" -`.

My understanding of grep is that it should be matching the full text of each of those words; the pipe in between each word should identify each word as its own pattern to be checked. How do I need to write this regex, and how can I specify whatever arguments I'd need in sed?

Comment: Instead of `[...]` use `(...)` for grouping: `sed -En '/(Train|Test|Recall)/p' scores`

Comment: @anubhava The six lines of scores at the bottom of the current output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square brackets `[]` contains a list of possible matching characters, so you often see examples like `gr[ae]y` to match both `gray` and `grey`.

For your usage you can omit the brackets `Train|Test|Recall`, or use parentheses `(Train|Test|Recall)`.

For `grep` in regular mode your command becomes

```
cat scores | grep "\(Train\|Test\|Recall\)"
```

Or in extended regex mode it becomes

```
cat scores | grep -E "(Train|Test|Recall)"
```

Or in `sed`:

```
cat scores | sed -E -n "/(Train|Test|Recall)/p"
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract just the scores lines use this extended grep command:

```
$ cat scores | egrep '^(Train|Test|Recall) scores:'
Train scores:
Test scores:
```

I presume you want the numbers following the scores lines as well:

```
$ cat scores | egrep '^(Train|Test|Recall) scores:|^ '
Train scores:
    Logistic Regression Recall: 0.6892336879192357
    Random Forest Recall: 0.5848905752422251
Test scores:
    Logistic Regression Recall: 0.6746186562629912
    Random Forest Recall: 0.5647724728982124
```

Explanation: The egrep has a `|^`  appended, meaning the previous regex *OR* lines beginning with a space.

For readability you can now combine the score and numbers:

```
$ cat scores | egrep '^(Train|Test|Recall) scores:|^ ' | perl -0777 -pe 's/(scores:)[^:]*: ([0-9\.]*)[^:]*: ([0-9\.]*)/$1 $2, $3/g'
Train scores: 0.6892336879192357, 0.5848905752422251
Test scores: 0.6746186562629912, 0.5647724728982124
```

Explanation:

- the `-0777` in the perl command replaces the `\n` line separator with octal `777` so that we can scan over newlines
- the `-pe` instructs perl to be a one liner command
- the `s/.../.../g` is a search and replace with `g` global flag